# Proof for Limitation Theorem for Euler-Summation

Tags: sequences-and-series, divergent-series, summation-method

I'm currently stuck in Hardy's Book 'Divergent Series' at a very small [Proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KauEQ.png) which i can't seem to grasp.

Here, $(E,q)$ Summation is defined over $\lim_{m \rightarrow \infty} A_m^{(q)}$ or $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_m^{(q)}$, where

$$
A_m^{(q)} = \sum_{n=0}^m \frac{1}{(q+1)^m} \binom{m}{n} q^{m-n} A_n \\ a_m^{(q)} = \sum_{n=0}^m \frac{1}{(q+1)^m} \binom{m}{n} q^{m-n} a_n
$$
where $A_m = \sum_{n=0}^m a_n$. The Operator E is defined over $E a_n = a_{n+1}$.

(8.2.4) is just the definition of $(E,q)$-Summation, while (8.2.5) is
$$
(q+1)^{m+1} a_m^{(q)} = (q+E)^m a_0
$$
which follows directly over the Binomial Formula.

Everything is clear to me except the key step from $a_n = (E+q-q)^n a_0$ to $a_n = o\{(q+1)^n + \binom{n}{1} q (q+1)^{n-1} + \cdots + q^n\}$ and am currently feeling very stupid. Any Help appreciated.

Comment: Looks to me like you just treat $(E+q-q)^n$ as $((E+q)-q)^n$ and use the binomial theorem (throwing away signs): $(E+q)^n+\binom{n}{1}q(E+q)^{n-1}+\cdots$. Then use what you know about $(E+q)^m$.

Comment: right, yeah, i am indeed stupid, thanks.

Comment: we all make silly mistakes! Thanks for asking a good first question and carefully thinking through where you were confused. Don't beat yourself up!